Is there an English translation of Jñanasrimitra's Isvaradusana ("Disproving God")?
I'm wondering whether there is an English translation of a work called "Isvaradusana" (lit. "Disproving God") written by the Buddhist philosopher Jñanasrimitra (fl. 975-1025 C.E.). I'd appreciate any guidance on finding where one can obtain an English version of this piece.
